# How do I align the Title text?

Tags: thingsboard

I am editing a widget in my new install. I have a temperature widget and I have been playing with the styling.

For the life of me, I can't seem to align the title of my widget to the center.

```
    {
      "fontWeight": 900,
      "textAlign": "center"
    }
    {
      "fontWeight": 900,
      "text-Align": "center"
    }
    {
      "fontWeight": 900,
      "align": "center"
    }
    {
      "fontWeight": 900,
      "fontAlign": "center"
    }
```

None of these permutations work. Any help?

Cheers,

Coach

Answer (score 0):

If that is CSS, try text-align :center;

If you want to bold the text try font-weight: bold;

Comment: Yeah this doesn't appear to be the case when using ThingsBoard as doesn't respond to CSS the way we all know it should.